# Amazon CloudFront Origin Access Denied, authentication requires the Signature, Expires and AWSAccessKeyId parameters

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

So I have been following the amazon tutorial to get the Origin Access Identity for serving private content with s3 bucket and CloudFront. Here is what I have done:

-created a cloudfront key pair.

-created origin access identity

-created a cloud front, gave it access and made it change the s3 rules accordingly.

But the java code does not seem to work. I am getting the following error when using the created URL:

**Query-string authentication requires the Signature, Expires and AWSAccessKeyId parameters**

Here is my code:

```
String policyResourcePath = "http://" + CloudFrontUrl + "/" + filename;     
    AmazonS3URI URI= new AmazonS3URI(policyResourcePath);
    String urIString = URI.toString();
    DateTime dt = new DateTime();
    Date added =dt.plusMinutes(5).toDate();     
    ClassPathResource res = new ClassPathResource(privateKeyFilePath); 
    Path path = Paths.get(res.getURI());
    byte[] privKeyByteArray = Files.readAllBytes(path);
    PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privKeyByteArray);
    KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    PrivateKey myPrivKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(keySpec);
    String policy = CloudFrontUrlSigner.buildCustomPolicyForSignedUrl(urIString , added, IPAddress,null);

    String singedUrl = CloudFrontUrlSigner.getSignedURLWithCustomPolicy(urIString , *My Cloud front key pair access key id*, myPrivKey, policy);

    System.out.println(singedUrl);
```

What am I missing?